# How can I create custom routes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web

I want to send a parameter to a default action in a default controller just like this:

```
Domain.com/parameter
```

`parameter` is just an id that I want to sent to an action

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC4 or later then you can have a much easier time of it using attribute based routing. I hate the old routing system you are using. If you switch to attribute based routing (very easy), then decorate your controller with this attribute:

```
RoutePrefix[("")]
```

This tells routing that this controller has no prefix, and therefore will be the controller used by default when you don't specify one in your URL.

Now find the action you want to use, and decorate it with this attribute:

```
Route[("{myParam:int}")]
```

This will then route requests as follows:

```
www.mydomain.com/10
```

And these requests will go to the controller and action you decorated, and the myParam parameter will contain 10.

Lots more info here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score -1):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Users",
            "{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = 
                                       "test",id=UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```